# How to use Journey Data to personalize Email when using Salesforce Entry Data

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect

I want to create an Email which contains the first name of the person to whom the mail is sent.
I am using the journey builder through which I am sending the mails and my entry source is Salesforce data. I'm not storing anything in data extension.
Is it possible to fetch the name of the person from the journey and print it in my mail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Markus got you covered. Check out his answer to the same question:

[Accessing data from journey object/event in Emails using Journey Builder](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/183399/accessing-data-from-journey-object-event-in-emails-using-journey-builder)

Hope that helps..

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Worked perfectly.
Thank You!